# Pandas Dataframe to_excel Excel function "inactive"/"non-evaluated"

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am using Pandas Dataframe to generate an Excel file where the cells will store the hyperlink. I am pretty positive that the HYPERLINK functions are valid.

```
def gen_link(sheet, cell, text):
    '''
    a utility function to generate the hyper link
    '''
    data = {
        'sheet': sheet,
        'cell': cell,
        'text': text
    }
    value = '=HYPERLINK("#{sheet}!{cell}","{text}")'.format(**data)
    value = value.upper()
    return value
```

However, when I open the output file in Excel, all the links looks unevaluated. I have to go to the cell, highlight the content and hit enter to activate it.

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) of `to_excel` does not provide that much information and I am wondering if the community knows the answer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following demo:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('d:/temp/a3.xlsx')

df.to_excel(writer, index=False)

book = writer.book

ws = book.worksheets()[0]

ws.write_formula('A1', '=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com", "Google")')

writer.save()
```

PS you may also want to check [worksheet.write_url()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#write_url) method